# Можно ли упростить работу с HTML файлами?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Вот бывает, верстаешь себе 20 HTML страниц и тут вдруг в футере нужно добавить блок. И приходится во всех 20-ти файлах его добавлять. Можно ли это как то сделать быстро везде и сразу?
P.S. Пользуюсь Sublime Text 2. Может в нем что есть, чего я не знаю?

Comment: Для этого есть php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSI, поднимается на любом простеньком локалхосте (WAMP и т.д.):

```
<!--#include virtual="/header.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/index.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html"-->
```

Другая страница:

```
<!--#include virtual="/header.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/about.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html"-->
```

Тем самым вы избавляете себя от повторения кода (header.html, footer.html) в разных страницах. Само собой, включения могут быть и сложней.

Comment: А как потом это разобрать на отдельные классические HTML файлы?

Comment: Это и есть "отдельные классические HTML-файлы": footer.html, index.html, about.html, header.html :) Или вы о чём?

Comment: Да. Но потом это все нужно собрать в файлы, где будут внутри футер, хедер, без всяких инклюдов для простого открытия в браузере

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос: а не рановато ли вам заниматься вебом? Серьёзно, без обид. Если вы таких элементарных вещей понять не можете...

Comment: Как бы 3 года уже верстаю и весьма качественно. Но чисто по классике. Создал страницу, скопировал, поменял контент, снова скопировал и поменял и т.д. А потом, когда 20 страниц и возникает необходимость правки в общем шаблоне, футере, например, то приходится открывать все 20 файлов, искать нужную строчку и менять

Comment: За три года можно было бы уже поднять локальный сервер и понять что к чему. Тем более что SSI это технологии не немного старше HTML, то есть ещё прошлого века.

Comment: Я понимаю, что к чему и как. Я говорю о том, что заказчику нужно отдавать в обычном виде, в коем делаю сейчас. Но при этом я хочу найти способ быстрой правки во всех файлах проекта

Comment: если вам совсем делать нечего, то сделайте на php/server side incudes а заказчику (он наверное очень рад от вас получать набор файлов ага, особенно его программист счастлив) отправляйте что-нить типа вывода wget -rk http://localhost/site

Comment: а вообще вы у них поинтересуйтесь что им удобнее, программисту всяко  проще, если отдельные блоки выдаются отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос :)

На сегодняшний день я использую плагин [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include) и билдую все исходники из `src` в `built`

Answer (score 1):

Футер один - выноси в файл, шапка одна - выноси в файл

Comment: Без всяких там PHP, есть всякие там JS. Но вопрос в другом - почему бы и не использовать PHP?

Comment: потому что это потом отправлять заказчику. И все должно быть в нормальном виде

Comment: >потому что это потом отправлять заказчику. И все должно быть в нормальном виде

Если у заказчика не поднят аналогичный сервер - тогда никак, вообще. А правильней всего показывать заказчику на своём сервере.

Comment: Пара минут гугления:> 15. Как произвести замену в нескольких файлах? Ctrl-Shift-F,  далее смотрите> поле WHERE, если нажать кнопку … , то> можно выбрать в каких файлах> производить замену.Кстати, во многих редакторах, предусмотрена замена по регулярному выражению. Это на тот случай, если есть какие-то расхождения в файлах. Цитата взята из [отсюда](http://labdes.ru/sublime-text-2-how-to), может пригодится.

Comment: Тогда - всё-таки поднять у себя простенький сервер и использовать SSI. См. ответ.

Comment: если не вы, так кто-нибудь другой будет разбивать страницу на блоки, это MVC и без него уж совсем никак, если не вы - так программист должен это знать, проконсультируйтесь у него)

Comment: @Deonis Видимо это единственный человеческий вариант) Спс

Comment: @inferus-vv это не человеческий вариант, а просто нечеловеческий. Не хотел бы я в поддержку получить сайт после такого вот "программиста"

Comment: @inferus-vv, да уж, рано вам пока с заказчиками дело иметь :)

Comment: @0xFFh Просто я, видимо, хочу сделать одну вещь, но не могу нормально дать остальным понять, что я хочу. Либо я вообще бред придумал))
P.S. Я уже заказов больше 100 выполнил, так что не надо..

Comment: А вы видеокурсы не ведёте? Просто интересно, не каждый специалист может похвастаться и 10 проектами, а у вас сто...